# problems with facet.sort parameter with solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to order facets from a single query with multiple facet queries.

But facet.order and facet.mincount are not working.

the query is:

```
facet.query=text:word1&facet.query=text:word2&facet.query=text:word3&facet=true&q=*:*&facet.mincount=50&facet.sort=count
```

I'm generating it with solrj

```
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.setFacet(true);
query.setFacetSort(FacetParams.FACET_SORT_COUNT); //count
query.setFacetMinCount(50);
query.addFacetQuery("text:word1");  
query.addFacetQuery("text:word2");
query.addFacetQuery("text:word3");
```

the response is:

```
...facet_counts={facet_queries={text:word1=597,text:word2=23,text:word3:1100},facet_fields={},facet_dates={},facet_ranges={}}}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

It seems that facet.field must be set to use the other facet.mincount and facet.sort. But it only affects to the words in facet field not the facet queries. Is that true? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either you do a "query faceting" (without extra parameters) or a "field faceting" that has all the parameters (mincount, order, etc)

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet

BTW, ampersand is missing after `q=*:*` in:

> facet.query=text:word1&facet.query=text:word2&facet.query=text:word3&facet=true&q=*:*facet.mincount=50&facet.sort=count

Comment: Yes, it was a hand made example. I missed out the &. Anyway. The question is, could I order the results from a multi faceted query search ?

Comment: I don't know of a way. If you do facet.field=text you will have them in order but for all the words of your texts...